# How do I find out if my wireless card supports 5 GHz?

Tags: linux, wifi, 802.1x

I have the

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
```

How do I find out if that card/driver support 5 GHz?

Comment: Related: [How to set wifi driver settings to prefer 5 GHz channel above 2.4 GHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183525/how-to-set-wifi-driver-settings-to-prefer-5-ghz-channel-above-2-4-ghz)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Find out the interface name, by running `iwconfig`

```
$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"EvanCarroll"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: D8:50:E6:44:B2:C8   
          Bit Rate=19.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:80   Missed beacon:0
```

In this case it is `wlan0`, then run `iwlist <interface> freq`,

```
$ iwlist wlan0 freq
wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
```

None of these channels are outside of 2.4 GHz. It does not support 5 GHz.

Comment: It'd be nice if you also showed how to do this with the `iw` tool as well. I think the others are possibly considered obsolete...

Comment: right. `iw phy` shows detailed capabilities. beside of this you may also find wifi cards that are capable of 5ghz, but the driver isn't.

Comment: and does this means the Linux driver does not support it or the card itself does not? Or to rephrase it: can this mean the driver simply does not support it?

Comment: @DanieleSegato I am unsure of how to answer that. The whole thing is predicated on there being a card with specific bands not supported by driver. That may exist. However, it sounds theoretical and it's another question.

Comment: @DanieleSegato, I don't know that answer for your question, but you can check the manufacture's website if your are in doubt. For the OP, for example: https://ark.intel.com/products/66888/Intel-Centrino-Wireless-N-2200-Single-Band. It says it is single band.

Comment: in my case the hardware do not support it. which is not an answer to my question tough :)

Comment: What if before switching to Ubuntu I was using 5Ghz Wi-Fi network on same laptop on Windows and after installing Ubuntu `iwlist <interface> freq` displays only 2.4 Ghz channels?

Comment: @colotiline it is totally possibly your wifi driver itself doesn't support 5ghz. I would be interesting in knowing your output to LSPCI, you should ask another question about that. specifically, "does <card> support 5ghz in linux"

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to discover what your card supports, `iw phy` is a nice solution with a **lot** more information (including supported bands).

`iwlist` is showing more what's available and/or allowed in your locale, what was disabled due to DFS channels, etc., not what your device supports. From the `iwlist` man page:

> ```
>    freq[uency]/channel
>           Give  the  list of available frequencies in the device and the number of defined channels. Please note that usually the
>           driver returns the total number of channels and only the frequencies available in the present locale, so  there  is  no
>           one-to-one mapping between frequencies displayed and channel numbers.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

When running iwconfig you will get the following possible information:

1. IEEE 802.11bgn = 2.4 GHz only
2. IEEE 802.11gn  = 2.4 GHz only
3. IEEE 802.11agn = 2.4 GHz + 5 GHz

Comment: That's simply factually incorrect, as 802.11n /can/ support 5ghz, even though it isn't require to support 5ghz by the spec.